# Data does not insert in database using java class and bean

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to Java Web Development. Started to Learn MVC. I am facing problem i.e data does not save in Database.
I do not get any Exception. RequestDispatcher Just Display the page i have included.

Sorry if i did not place this question in write Category.

Code is here

Controller Code:

```
package manipulationStudentData;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(description = "Insertion Of Data", urlPatterns = { "/InsertionOfData" })
public class InsertionController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public InsertionController() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  
ServletException, IOException {
    ManipulateStudentBean insertStudentData=new ManipulateStudentBean();
    DatabaseActivityDao database=new DatabaseActivityDao();

    String date=""+request.getParameter("day")+"-"+request.getParameter("month")+"-
    "+request.getParameter("year");

    Date dob=null;

    try{
         dob=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    insertStudentData.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
    insertStudentData.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
    insertStudentData.setFatherName(request.getParameter("fatherName"));
    insertStudentData.setGender(request.getParameter("gender"));
    insertStudentData.setDob(dob);
    insertStudentData.setClassNo(request.getParameter("classNo"));
    insertStudentData.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));

    database.InsertData(insertStudentData);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/ManipulationPage.jsp").include(request, response);


}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request,response);
}

}
```

BeanClass:

```
package manipulationStudentData;

import java.util.Date;

public class ManipulateStudentBean {

   int studentId;
String firstName="";
String lastName="";
String fatherName="";
String gender="";
  Date dob;
String classNo="";
String address="";


public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}
public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getFatherName() {
    return fatherName;
}
public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public String getClassNo() {
    return classNo;
}
public void setClassNo(String classNo) {
    this.classNo = classNo;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}
```

Insertion to Database Code just adding the Method here:

```
  public void InsertData(ManipulateStudentBean studentdata){



    String query="INSERT INTO students  
    (FirstName,LastName,FatherName,Gender,DateOfBirth,Class,Address) VALUES "
    + "('" + studentdata.getFirstName() +" ' ' "+ studentdata.getLastName() +" ' '"+ 
    studentdata.getFatherName() +" '  '" +  studentdata.getGender() +" '  '"+ 
    studentdata.getDob() +" '  '" + studentdata.getClassNo() 
    + " '  '" + studentdata.getAddress() + " '  '" ;

    try{

        connection=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        stment=connection.createStatement();
        stment.executeQuery(query);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

finally{

        /*Closing Statement*/

        try{
            if(stment !=null){
                stment.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*Closing Connection*/

        try{
            if(connection !=null){
                connection.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
 }
```

Same query works i have checked without using MVC Model.

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: no  the ManipulationPage.jsp comes when i check the database data is not inserted

Comment: Do you use a JDBC driver to create a connection to the database?

Comment: I don't think that an Insert statemant that looks like this will work: `INSERT INTO students (...) VALUES ('value1' 'value2' ...)`. You're missing a lot of commas in that `VALUES` part. Also you're missing a closing parentheses in that query.

Comment: yes, the query itself is not created properly, in that case you will get an exception, check your server logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like this:

```
String query="INSERT INTO students  
    (FirstName,LastName,FatherName,Gender,DateOfBirth,Class,Address) VALUES "
    + "('" + studentdata.getFirstName() +" ', ' "+ studentdata.getLastName() +" ', '"+ 
    studentdata.getFatherName() +" ',  '" +  studentdata.getGender() +" ' , '"+ 
    studentdata.getDob() +" ' , '" + studentdata.getClassNo() 
    + " ' , '" + studentdata.getAddress() + " ' )" ;
```

as suggested by Tom you are missing commas & closing bracket.

As you are just catching the exception and printing the stacktrace you will see the exception in server logs and after that the servlet is forwarding the request to JSP page.

Alternatively, instead of using statement you can use prepared statement, see the example here:

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/